# Cannot borrow as immutable - String and len()

Tags: rust, immutability, mutability, borrow-checker

```
let mut result = String::with_capacity(1000);

result.push_str("things... ");
result.push_str("stuff... ");

result.truncate((result.len() - 4));
```

However, this is a compile error. Something to do with the borrow checker and possibly mutability.

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `result` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
 --> <anon>:7:22
  |
7 |     result.truncate((result.len() - 4));
  |     ------           ^^^^^^           - mutable borrow ends here
  |     |                |
  |     |                immutable borrow occurs here
  |     mutable borrow occurs here
```

Yet, if I change it slightly I am allowed to do this:

```
let newlen = result.len() - 4;
result.truncate(newlen);
```

Why? Is there a way to change this so it can be written in one line? (P.S. this is on Rust 1.0)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is an unfortunate shortcoming of Rust borrow checking procedure. This essentially happens because

```
result.truncate(result.len() - 2)
```

is equivalent to

```
String::truncate(&mut result, result.len() - 2)
```

and here you can see that because arguments are computed in left-to-right order, `result` is indeed borrowed mutably before it is used in `result.len()`.

I found this problem in Rust issue tracker: [#6268](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/6268). This issue was closed in favor of [non-lexical borrows RFC issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/811). It seems that it's just one of those things which would be nice to have but which needed more time to be done that it was available before 1.0. [This](http://blog.ezyang.com/2013/12/two-bugs-in-the-borrow-checker-every-rust-developer-should-know-about/) post may also be of some interest (even though it is almost two years old).

Comment: That helps to clarify. It's more of an annoyance than anything. So the error is related to a conflict between `truncate` needing mutability and `len` needing immutability? It would seem that `result.len()` would have its work completed before handing over to truncate, meaning this is more of a compiler quirk than anything? http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.len

Comment: You're almost correct - the problem is that `truncate` requires `&mut self` which prohibits *any* subsequent borrowing in the same scope. And yes, it *would* seem that `result.len()` is completed before it is handed over to `truncate()`, however, my answer explains why it is not so - actually, the method receiver is computed *before* arguments, and so `&mut result` is in scope *before* `&result` required by `result.len()`.

Comment: @jocull, you can find more in the issues I've linked to in my update if you're interested in it.

Comment: Great information - thanks so much! Chalking it up to a compiler quirk that is just part of life for now.